# Plane not rendering, but is visible in materials mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Hi I'm using Cycles Render in Blender and I have a problem where I made a new plane put color on it and it is not showing up when I render it, but shows in other modes. I'm not using different layers, the material isn't transparent and the camera icon is enabled for it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So, if it's not related to the "Duplication" settings... can you show also the Material settings?

Comment: (If it's just a simple scaled plane, however, I'd maybe suggest just making a new one? Although I understand that it's frustrating not to trace where the problem arises from)

Comment: Just to eliminate really simple slips that anyone can make.. .. Cycles settings?

Comment: [download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/z3tml7ge5bo5jgs/series0.zip). I think it'd be better if you took a look at it by download it and checking out all of my settings. Also what do you mean by cycles settings, what section can i find that under?

Comment: ... that's a train, not a plane :-)

Comment: Well, I was stumped.. I couldn't get anything to render at all on my downloaded copy.. and I couldn't find any dodgy settings.  Twice, though, I've managed to kick it into working by going to Blender render, rendering a default cube on another layer,  switching to PNG output, and switching back to Cycles, But it's not consistent, and weird. It now works when I switch back to mpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried here but anything isn't rendered.

But I found a simple solution to this issue.

Select all and copy  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>C</kbd> .

Create a new document: File >> New.

Paste now  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>V</kbd> .

In my case, all is rendered now.

Just to mention: the animation is copied too.

Comment: Yes, that's my last resort and just tried it and it works, just wondered what initially caused the issue in the first place. When I first created the project, it was in blender render and later I changed it to cycles renders, perhaps that's what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

The "Duplication" setting of your *Plane* object, which now looks like this:

[image]

should be set to "None".

Comment: It is none. I watched other tutorials to fix it and none of them helped me.

Comment: I took this image from your screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFasp.png) where it looks like it is "Group"

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/ZG01j4E.png) Here is a pic of at none. Same result

Comment: @Fox454x did you re-render after choosing None in Duplication settings?